# Uninstall/Downgrade Magento

Tags: magento, magento2

I am starting a new job next month, and they have asked me to familiarize myself with Magento.

I installed WAMP and Magento2 succesfully, and then realized later on that they had specified that I should familiarize myself with Magento1, not Magento2.

I used composer to install Magento2.

I need to uninstall 2, and install 1. I have already downloaded the .zip that I need to install 1, but I am unable to proceed - composer, when I use it to try to install Magento1, says there is "Nothing to install or update".

How do I go about uninstalling Magento2, so that I can try to install Magento1?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity I strongly disagree. The third and fourth bullet points at the top of the page you yourself linked justify this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can uninstall M2 using `bin/magento setup:uninstall` then manually remove the files, and download and install M1.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 1.x is not under composer at all, so you will have to install it manually on a web server.